# c++ boost insertion fails

Tags: c++, boost, find, insertion, bimap

I've defined boost::bimap-

```
typedef boost::bimap    
<
        boost::bimaps::unordered_set_of <CrString>, 
        boost::bimaps::unordered_set_of <RU64>
    > xBimap
```

each time i check whether i already have the value in the bimap -

```
// Take iterator to the left node
    xBimap::left_iterator left_iter = m_bimap.left.find(CrString(pi_pLeft));

    // Check if found
    if(left_iter != m_bimap.left.end()) // Found
```

and if not i'm inserting to it using the command-

```
m_bimap.insert(xBimap::value_type(pi_pLeft, pi_nRight));
```

i sometimes don't find the string in the hash although it does exist and in other cases i've already found the exact same string. Then,  when i try to insert the value again to the bimap, i see that the number of values in the bi-map doesn't change.

Do you know what can be the reason that i don't find the string in the hash?

Thanks.

Comment: Show more code.The info is not enough!

Comment: like what? 
I addition i've printed the bi-map and i see that the string in still there and looks valid.